# ruby -e 'puts "something"' does not output anything on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, bundler

This is what happens on a Debian machine

```
$ ruby -e 'puts "something"'
something
$
```

This is what I expected.

However, when I run the same on my Mac (OS X 10.7.3), I get

```
1.9.3-p125-perf $ ruby -e "puts 'something'"

1.9.3-p125-perf $ ruby -e "print 'something'"
1.9.3-p125-perf $ rbenv shell 1.8.7-p358
1.8.7-p358 $ ruby -e "puts 'something'"

1.8.7-p358 $ ruby -e "print 'something'"
nil1.8.7-p358 $ rbenv shell system
system $ ruby -e "puts 'something'"

system $ ruby -e "print 'something'"
nilsystem $
```

Does anyone know what's going on here and how I get ruby to output something meaningful again?

My Ruby versions:

1.9.3-p125-perf: `ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]`

1.8.7-p358: `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i686-darwin11.3.0]`

system: `ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]`

Scripts or IRB work fine, piping ruby also works:

```
1.9.3-p125-perf $ cat | ruby
puts "foo"
^D
foo
```

It's just the `ruby -e` that behaves funky.
This also happens on my girlfirends Mac. She uses RVM.

Comment: What's the output of `ruby --version`?

Comment: 1.9.3-p125-perf: `ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]`, 1.8.7-p358: `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i686-darwin11.3.0]`, system: `ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]`

Comment: Hm, seems normal. What if you run a .rb file with that `puts` line?

Comment: Maybe your rbenv install is messed up. I myself use RVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit. I was using an old version of [bundler-exec](https://github.com/gma/bundler-exec).

`bundler-exec` creates shell aliases for a predefined list of commands and wraps them in this function:

```
run-with-bundler()
{
    if bundler-installed && within-bundled-project; then
        bundle exec "$@"
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}
```

The version I had was missing the quotation marks around the `$@` which somehow caused ruby to misbehave.